# CSS Grid does not grow when inside flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

My understanding of CSS Grid is that it will grow to fill its parent, however that does not seem to work correctly when the parent's size is controlled by a flexbox.

In [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-gds31u?file=index.html), I expected the light blue grid items to grow to cover the red area. This works correctly if the grid is on it's own, however it does not grow at all once it is placed into a flex element (even with `flex-grow: 1`);

What is happening here and is there any way to adjust the style to behave as I expect?

---

**Code:**

*Layout*

```
<div class="normal-grid">
  <div class="grid-item">Thing 1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-grid">
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Style*

```
.normal-grid {
  height: 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  background: red;
}

.flex {
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-grid {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  background: red;
}

.grid-item {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply keep the `row` direction (the default one) and you will have the stretch effect:

```css
.normal-grid {
  height: 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  background: red;
}

.flex {
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  /*flex-direction: column;*/
}

.flex-grid {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  background: red;
}

.grid-item {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="normal-grid">
  <div class="grid-item">Thing 1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-grid">
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but any idea why?  This seems like a bug.

Comment: @SephReed yes probably a bug that get fixed because the issue no more occur acctually

Answer (score 1):

You can add `flex-basis: 100%;` to `.flex-grid` in order to get the behavior you wish for.

```css
.normal-grid {
  height: 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  background: red;
}

.flex {
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-grid {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  background: red;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.grid-item {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="normal-grid">
  <div class="grid-item">Thing 1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-grid">
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When elements are controlled by a flexbox, their initial dimensions have to come into consideration. in this case, `.flex-grid` seems to be shrinking - so adding `flex-basis: 100%` will tell the browser that its initial size should be 100% of its size.

Comment: In addition, adding `height: 0;` to `.flex-grid` has the same effect in this case