# Grid inside flexbox not working as expected in firefox (max-width and percentage problem ?)

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

I have a problem when using grid display inside flexbox container. I intend the flexbox container to grow in width depending on grid elements, and it works like that on chrome/edge but it has different behaviour on Firefox.

I think that the problem is with max-width implementation on firefox, as far as I can tell there is a problem with percentage values, (when I change it to constant value it works as expected, I can also make width: 100%, or make flex-basis:100%, but it will make the flexbox div take the whole width all the time, and I would like it to remain responsive (have width depending on amount of items inside grid), so solutions given there: [CSS Grid does not grow when inside flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974759/css-grid-does-not-grow-when-inside-flexbox) are not helpful in my case.

Here is codepen with example of the problem: [Grid in flex container](https://codepen.io/piechoo/pen/RwLQBKJ) , you can see it behaves different if you open it in chrome and firefox (I would like it to behave everywhere as it is behaving in chrome)
Thanks for any help

```css
.flex {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width:100vw;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-grid {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  background: red;
}

.grid-item {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-grid">
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The behavior of Firefox seems the correct one for me.

Comment: Why? If that's the correct behavior then why it works chrome-like with constant (not percentage) max-width?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider a different implementation like below:

```css
.flex {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 150px); /* dont use 1fr */
}

.flex-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: inherit; /* inherit the same layout */
  grid-column: 1/-1; /* take all the available columns */
  background: red;
}

.grid-item {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-grid">
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Thing 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your sollution indeed solves this simple example, I adjusted it a little bit according to my needs (code in codepen should be updated by now), however I am still puzzled why flexbox implementation behaves different on firefox and chrome.

Comment: @PiotrPiechowicz don't be puzzled, There are a lot of difference between browsers ;) One of them is having a bug or both are not interpreting the specification the same way

Comment: EDIT: Unfortunately, your sollution doesn't work as i would like to, the container is not resposible, it just behaves like my flexbox sollution with flex-basis or constant width

Comment: Of course I meant to write responsive not responsible :)